# How Do I Change This Bootstrap to work on Joomla the way I need?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I want to have this bootstrap menu I'm creating and will use for many shows on our website to be a plain nav-tabs menu with the Social and info links on the right side. But I can't figure out the code. I'm wondering if someone can help us with the code and change it so it uses the nav-tabs instead of the normal nav & looks clean instead of the gray block it's in currently...

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
  </a>
  <a class="brand" href="#">Name Of Show</a>
  <div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Cast</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Episodes</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>    
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-default" style="color:#3b5998;margin-top:-2px;"   href="#">
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" title="Facebook"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" style="color:#00aced;margin-top:-2px;"        href="#">
<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" title="Twitter"></i>
</a>
<button type="button" style="height:39px;margin-top:-2px;" class="btn  btn-inverse">TV-14</button>
<button type="button" style="height:39px;margin-top:-2px;" class="btn btn-default disabled">1 Season | HD | 2011</button>
</div>
</ul>
  </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
</div>
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who helps me with this. I've been stuck for days...

Answer (score 0):

With Protostar Template (one of default templates in Joomla!) you could use the nav-tabs instead of nav-pills or others Bootstrap classes opening the administration panel > module > menu > advanced > Menu Class Suffix; and inside the field write simply nav-tabs  after a space.

If you want substitute the entire HTML code of menu you have to build a new Joomla! module or try to modify the php files here: joomla root/modules/mod_menu/tmpl